# Download Response Data as Stream w/ Axios in React App

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, fetch-api

### Issue

I need to download query results from an endpoint by streaming results to a CSV file. This is in an effort to support enormous ResultSets being sent through the browser at one time.

Is there a way to accomplish this using Axios in the context of a React App?

I have seen [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and know that it has the following characteristics:

- returns ReadableStream
- Is NOT supported by IE11
- Does NOT allow for intercepting requests
- The **status** of a response relates to the request itself, not the HTTP status

  - This means that the only way to receive an error would be to have something go wrong with the stream ending prematurely
  - This definitely won't work for me since I have custom error-handling related to user permissions

Besides the `ReadableStream` response type, the rest of the characteristics listed are not permissible. I will need to support IE11 and allow for intercepting requests / reading the HTTP status to determine how to handle the traffic.

### Example with `fetch`:

```js
      // The promise returned by `fetch` rejects if the fetch was unable to make HTTP-request
      //  e.g. network problems, or there’s no such site.
      // Abnormal HTTP-statuses, such as 404 or 500 do not cause an error.
      const results = await fetch(`${URL}/data`, {
        method: 'post', // HTTP POST to send query to server
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*', // indicates which files we are able to understand
          'Content-Type': 'application/json', // indicates what the server actually sent
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(query), // server is expecting JSON
        credentials: 'include', // sends the JSESSIONID cookie with the address
      }).then(res => res.json()) // turn the ReadableStream response back into JSON
        .then((res) => {
          if (res.ok) {
            // boolean, true if the HTTP status code is 200-299.
            console.log('response.ok!');
          } else if (res.status === 401) {
            throw Error(`You are not authenticated. Please login.`);
          } else if (res.status === 403) {
            throw Error(`You are not authorized to access this data.`);
          } else {
            throw Error(`Request rejected with status ${res.status}`);
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          // catches error case and if fetch itself rejects
          error.response = {
            status: 0,
            statusText:
              'Cannot connect. Please make sure you are connected to internet.',
          };
          throw error;
        });

      console.log(results);
```

### Example with `axios` (not streaming)

#### Axios instance

```js
import ...
const Api = axios.create({
  baseURL: `${URL}`,
  withCredentials: true,
});

// attach interceptors to requests and responses
// these are defined elsewhere and imported
Api.interceptors.request.use((request) => requestHandler(request));
Api.interceptors.response.use((response) => successHandler(response), (error) => errorHandler(error));

export default Api;
```

#### Axios request

```js
const query = {"selections":{"TABLE_A":["COLUMN1"]},"filters":[{"predicates":[]}],"joins":[],"sorts":[],"limit":100,"offset":0}
const response = await Api.post('/data', query);
// further transformations to response to get formatted csv results required
```

### Questions about Axios

- Is it possible to have a `ReadableStream` in Axios same as `fetch`?
- Is streaming in Axios only possible when assuming that it will be supported by Node in a server-side only setting?

  - Sites like [this](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/download-files-images-with-axios-in-node-js) appear to say that using `responseType: 'stream'` isn't something that can be done in the browser, only with Node.js using `fs`
- Is it possible to use `fetch` or something else in conjunction with Axios?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Streaming a response from the browser is **not** currently supported :

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/479

Since we're dealing with `XMLHttpRequests` in the browser, Axios is limited to the specification set by `whatwg`. :

- https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-xmlhttprequest
- https://github.com/whatwg/xhr

Specifically, these are the only supported types :

```js
enum XMLHttpRequestResponseType {
  "",
  "arraybuffer",
  "blob",
  "document",
  "json",
  "text"
};
```

`stream` is accepted when setting a `responseType` in axios, but this is misleading. The adapter is going to be `xhr.js` implicitly since we are using the browser which relies on XMLHttpRequests. HttpRequests are made on the server-side and will allow axios to use the `http.js` adapter. THEN you can use `stream` as a ResponseType with Node.js.

Using the [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) API seems to be the only solution with a `ReadableStream` as a response body type.

Answer (score -1):

If you just need to download a file, using `blob` in the `responseType` options is definitely okay.

```js
axios.post(url, param, 
  { header: {...}, responseType: 'blob' }
)
 .then(res => {
      const link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = URL.createObjectURL(res);
      link.click();
  })
```

Comment: The question mentioned "enormous ResultSets" which means there's a good chance that all the data cannot be held in memory. Streaming would then help get the chunks piece by piece without having to first hold the entire blog in memory.