# More generic question about receiving a stream with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, stream, axios

## **I have a more generic question about receiving a stream with JavaScript**

Given the *generic use case*: I want to get data from backend (csv file, ...) to frontend.

Given the following *restrictions*:

- Backend just accepts 'POST' (non negotiable)
- Frontend uses 'Axios' (could be adjusted)

**How would I do that?**

All the examples in the network work with stream to get data like csv etc., I'm convinced that that's the way to go but couldn't explain it.

**My situation**

So far I tried a lot to make it work, I did actually but I don't think it was really "Streaming".

**Backend**: I pushed my stream into the *OutputStream* of the *response* and returned the stream. That means the data is visible in the devTools which shoudn't be. Without that, just returning the stream and not writing it to the OutputStream, I always got an "Network error", the backend returned successfully (I guess) but still I got the error.

**Frontend**: After some time I assume I realized why I got probably got the "Network error": [Axios does not support stream](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/479) 
Furthermore I use a *fileDownloader* that simulates a download click to download the response (POST fetch with Axios) which I formatted into a *Blob*.

**What is necessary to make *streaming* work? Is there an agenda?**

I don't want to fabricate stupid stuff and go somewhere I shouldn't go. That's why I would like to get some information from people who have already some experience with that.

- Do I need 'GET' to make streaming work? Or does it work with 'POST' too?
- In the backend returning the stream without writing it to the output of the response body is enough?
- Is Streaming the right way?

*What do I use?* *Frontend: React, TypeScript, Axios | Backend: C#*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60044205/download-response-data-as-stream-w-axios-in-react-app

The post suggests using fetch api instead of axios

Comment: Thanks, have read this one already. But now that you mention it again I saw the this one is also using 'POST'. Have overseen that before.